# Finding number of rows(phone number which having spaces) in a table

Tags: sql, db2

I need to find out the number of records in a table which having spaces in their `phone_number` field.

I have a table Address(`Addr_id`,`name`,`Street`,`pin`,`phone_number`).

The user can enter the phone_number with spaces. I need to find out the records which having the spaces in their phone_number.

Please note the user can enter his `phone_number` with any multiple spaces(`212 23 34 52` or `3434 344 667` or `23435 45 234`)

Please suggest a sql query to get the results

Answer (score 5):

One query that will give you results that have at least one space is:

```
SELECT * FROM Address
WHERE phone_number LIKE '% %';
```

To remove all spaces you can use the [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE Address 
SET phone_number = REPLACE(phone_number,' ','')
```

Comment: Now I need to remove these spaces from the phone number.Please suggest

Comment: @Rajasekhar. I added an option to replace spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM Address
WHERE phone_number LIKE '% %'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the number of records:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Address
WHERE phone_number LIKE '% %'
```

**Or**
If you want all the records:

```
SELECT *
FROM Address
WHERE phone_number LIKE '% %'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
select * from Address where phone_number like '% %'?
```

Not sure if this will work and actually match the space. Otherwise, you will need to look up the character code for a space and use that instead.